# how to avoid messy codes when outputting Chinese characters

Tags: string, windows, haskell, encode

I've found a strange problem about writing Chinese characters into a file by `writeFile`.

```
> writeFile "r.txt" "过"  -- outputting as expected.
```

[image]

```
> writeFile "r.txt" "图"  -- not displaying as expected. see the following:
```

[image]

Then the stranger thing happens:

```
> writeFile "r.txt" "图画"  -- outputting is normal, as follows:
```

[image]

More examples that display messy codes:

```
> writeFile "r.txt" "士"
> writeFile "r.txt" "十"
> writeFile "r.txt" "千"
> writeFile "r.txt" "一"
> writeFile "r.txt" "一千十士图" -- This is displayed as messy codes.
```

But the following is normal:

```
> writeFile "r.txt" "一千十士图画" -- This is normal.
```

So it's normal if the characters above are exported together with other characters that can be displayed normally such as `writeFile "r.txt" "十过"`。

I have no idea why this happens:

—— Why some characters are outputted as messy codes while others don't? In fact, "一千十士图" are the most used characters in Chinese.

—— Why the characters exported as messy codes can be displayed normally together with other characters that can be displayed normally?

I appreciate it if anyone can provide some information.

Comment: All of your "This is displayed as messy codes." examples are working on my computer (Ubuntu, GHCI, version 7.10.3). Probably haskell is using a slightly different file encoding then your text editor?

Comment: @quant my computer is Windows 10, GHCI, version 8.2.2. The same problem also exists in Windows 7, GHCI, version 8.0.2

Comment: What encoding does your text editor use?

Comment: Have you tried importing `System.IO.UTF8` instead of `System.IO`?

Comment: What encoding do you expect to be in the file? Could you verify with their actual byte content rather than what notepad shows?

Comment: @DanielWagner The output file uses UTF-8.

Comment: @Z-Y.L That's good to know, but it's not what I asked. For the file to display correctly, the program creating the file and the program reading the file have to agree on an encoding. So: what encoding does your text editor use? (And how do you know?) My guess is that your editor is trying to auto-detect an encoding and getting it wrong sometimes.

Comment: @DanielWagner The Windows' nodpad should use ANSI by default, since when I saveAs a new-created file, the default encoding shows as ANSI.

Comment: @ice1000 With `System.IO.UTF8` imported, the output is normal. But I don' t know why the default `writeFile` doesn't work.

Comment: What does "chcp" show you before you start ghci?

Comment: Apparently writeFile's encoding depends on the current locale. With ghc 8.2.2 from stack lts-10.4 at Windows 10 I cannot reproduce it with both codepage 936 (gb2312) and 65001 (utf-8)

Comment: I used (g)vim to view the file ("`:e ++enc=<encoding> r.txt`" to open file with explicit encoding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, this is an excellent question. Encoding issues are a problem still, even now. [Windows uses UTF-16 by default now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), while much of Haskell is developed on UTF-8 platforms. The actual encoding used by the `System.IO` functions isn't well-defined at runtime since it's set by the platform environment, or is chosen arbitrarily if not.

The first thing to do is switch to [`Data.Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) for text handling. Not only is this more aware of encodings, it's also considerably more efficient than the "List of Characters" model that `String` is. It has it's [own I/O functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text-IO.html) that take specific encodings into account, too.

To make this easier, enabling the [`OverloadedStrings`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overloaded-string-literals) will be very helpful. Also, since you're using string literals, checking that the source code file encoding matches the environment when GHC compiles it will help, too. There are a lot of places handling that data, and past a certain point, loading your strings from a known-good file ends up being less of a headache than putting them in the source.

Comment: Using I/O function such as `writeFile` from Data.Text.IO still results in strange characters in the output file when writing "图". But I think it's related to the encoding used by Windows, since I type “图" directly into a notepad and save it, it shows messy codes when I reopen it. But regarding string, `Data.Text` is a better tool. Thanks for your advice!